# 'kotlin' searching for data in editTextText in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rky4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSQ5c.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2DHs.png)

-if the data in editTextText2 is in the database, I want to print it to textview.
-I've read a lot of articles and watched videos, but I couldn't adapt it to my own. most of them are not in the kotlin language, and I am a novice.
-they printed out the entire database or searched for a certain word. i did these things.i want to search for the data in editTextText2.(the search will be in column col_name)

MainActivity.kt

```
binding.button3.setOnClickListener{
            var data = db.readData()
            binding.textView.text =""
            /*for (i in 0 until data.size){
                binding.textView.append(data.get(i).id.toString()+" "
                        +data.get(i).adsoyad+" "+data.get(i).yasi+"\n")}*/
            for (i in 0 until data.size){
               if (binding.editTextText2.toString()==data.get(i).adsoyad){binding.textView.append(data.get(i).adsoyad+"\n")}
                else{binding.textView.text="yeni"+"\n"}

            }

    }
```

DataBaseHelper.kt

```
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import android.widget.Toast

val database_name = "veritabanim"
val table_name = "kullanicilar"
val col_name = "adisoyadi"
val col_age = "yasi"
val col_id = "id"
class DataBaseHelper (var context: Context):SQLiteOpenHelper(context,
    database_name,null,1) {
    override fun onCreate(p0: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        var createTable = " CREATE TABLE "+ table_name+"("+
                col_id +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
                col_name +" VARCHAR(256),"+
                col_age +" INTEGER)"
        p0?.execSQL(createTable)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(p0: SQLiteDatabase?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
    fun insertData(kullanici: kullanici){
        val db =this.writableDatabase
        val cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(col_name,kullanici.adsoyad)
        cv.put(col_age,kullanici.yasi)
        var sonuc =db.insert(table_name,null,cv)
        if (sonuc ==(-1).toLong()){
            Toast.makeText(context,"hatali",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context,"başsarili",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    fun readData(): MutableList<kullanici> {
        var liste:MutableList<kullanici> = ArrayList()
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        var sorgu = "Select * from "+table_name
        var sonuc = db.rawQuery(sorgu,null)
        if (sonuc.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                var kullanici = kullanici()
                kullanici.yasi = sonuc.getString(sonuc.getColumnIndexOrThrow(col_age)).toInt()
                kullanici.id = sonuc.getString(sonuc.getColumnIndexOrThrow(col_id)).toInt()
                kullanici.adsoyad = sonuc.getString(sonuc.getColumnIndexOrThrow(col_name))
                liste.add(kullanici)
            }while (sonuc.moveToNext())
        }
        sonuc.close()
        db.close()
        return liste
    }



}
```

kullanici.kt

```
class kullanici {
    var id:Int=0
    var adsoyad:String=""
    var yasi:Int=0
    constructor(adsoyad:String,yasi:Int){
        this.adsoyad =adsoyad
        this.yasi =yasi
    }
    constructor(){}
}
```

Comment: give me an example that what do you want to do? are you trying to search a data and print it in textview?

Comment: the user will write text to the edittext and click on the button. if the text he wrote exists in the col_name column in the database, he will write the text to textview, if not, he will write not found.

Comment: I had created a similar project to understand sqlite...i can help you with that code? do you need it?

Comment: “It could be. i also work to learn. if you share it here, I will study it and try to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so as you asked I am sharing a snippet of the necessary code here so that you could implement the same by watching this.

First of all this is a function to search in database in DataBaseHelper.kt file.

**1.Scenario : You only want the exact word that you typed in the edittext.**

```
    fun searchUser(name: String): ArrayList<kullanici> {
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        val model: ArrayList<kullanici> = ArrayList<kullanici>()
        val cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE username =? ", arrayOf(name))
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {  
             //here we have to add the fields to the model from database. 
             //in your case it is 3 beacause you have 3 columns.

               model.add(kullanici(cursor.getString(1),
               cursor.getString(2),
               cursor.getString(3)))
        
            } while (cursor.moveToNext())
            cursor.close()
        }
        return model
    }
```

**Note:** I have taken arraylist because my database can have same multiple names.You can customze as per your requirement.

**2nd Scenario:if you type app, it will return all entries which has app in it. eg. apple, app, application etc.**

For that you just need to change the query a bit.
 `val cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE username LIKE \"%$name%\"",null)`

Now you call the function in your activity or fragment like this.I have used a `recyclerView` but as u have used textView I have customised the code for you.

```
   btnSearch.setOnClickListener{
           val str = edtSearch.text.toString()
           if (str.isNotEmpty()){
               val searchData = dBhandler.searchUser(str)

//as you have multiple data in aaray list and arraylist returns your model you cannot directly set in text view. as "adsoyad" is your name field i guess
               val sb = StringBuilder()
               searchData.forEach{
                sb.append(it.adsoyad).append("\n")
                 }
               txtName.text = sb.toString()
           }
           else{
               Toast.makeText(this,"No Matching entries found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
           }
       }
```

**Manage the arrayList as per your requirement.You can return only String in Database Helper if you do not allow multiple names in database. Else If you do have multiple same name entries, would recommend to set those names in recyclerview instead of textView.**

**In Short: Take Overview and manage accordingly. The main thing was the query that i gave you. Hope this helps**

Comment: i will try it at the first opportunity

Comment: in my code `user_details` is my table name and `username` is the column name.

Comment: I think I'm making a mistake somewhere again. there are 2 results from the word I'm looking for in my database. output:  [com.example.sqlite.kullanici@42a41bc0,com.example.sqlite.kullanici@42a41ce8]  i'm really tiring you out, I'm sorry

Comment: @Sezar what fuctionality do you want if there are more than 1 result? do u want to print that result two times or just one? or do something else?

Comment: I want this. the more results there are, the more I want to print. the problem is that the output is incorrect. I'm doing it wrong somewhere. I added a picture to the question. i have problems and codes.

Comment: @Sezar I just saw your images and I have changed the code accordingly just add the part after the comments. I have explaiined why to use that. 

NOTE** if you have same name 5 times the textview will have the same name 5 times. If you want once just remove the for each and directly set the 0th index to the textView.

Comment: I hope now your issue will be solved if not. do let me know

Comment: Ok. i made a copy and paste of your codes. I've fixed it with a few small changes on it. I thank you very much. you made time for me. now let's not try to understand these things, and I have to learn. this was my sqlite learning app. after learning it thoroughly, I will integrate it into my application in my mind. I am thankful to you

Comment: no need to thank...we are here to help..if it workd for you please accept the answer and upvote it, so that if one faces such problem can find the answer easily.

Comment: unfortunately, my reputation is not enough for me to vote. when I reach 15 reputations, I will come back and vote.

Comment: its enough to accept as answer. I am happy that my code/ logic helped you

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el9KV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMIIR.png)

For Sqlite control, you can write a control function in the DAO section, that is, in the operations section, as in the first photo, this function checks how many of that data there are. In my example I checked with id, you can check with other unique data. In the second picture, this control is being run, the bundle.id part there is my incoming data, you can save your own data and if the control data !=0 you can say print to textview. In this example, I use it for control so that the same data is not added when adding data to the cart.

Comment: I'm not on a computer, so I'm trying. if what you have written will give the number of data I want, or if it will prevent the same data from being entered again, that's not what I want. I understand this from Google translate. i have an edittextim where I saved a name to the database. i want to do a check in the database using another edittext. i want to print the result in textview. if there is, he will write the data I want, or he will write it not found.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you, I use a control code instead of a search to check if a data exists. I hope you find the answer

Comment: Please [edit✏️] to paste the text used in the image into your answer so that it can be read on all devices, edited, copied as text, and found through search. As it stands now, your image makes it hard to view and use your answer. See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.